# How can I get my accessibility settings to apply to my 2nd monitor on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, accessibility

I use Windows 10 and adjust display settings (high contrast theme, mouse/cursor pointer size, and dpi) to be able to see my work. I just added a 2nd monitor and run extended display. The high contrast theme carried over but not the mouse size or dpi.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 each screen has separate density settings. Windows will try to match them to make stuff similarly sized in physical dimensions. It looks like it didn't take your settings into account.

You can adjust individual screen's dpi settings in the *Display settings* panel. It's available by right-clicking empty space on desktop and selecting *Display settings*.